# How to make changes to live laravel application without breaking the website?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a live laravel project created by an old employee. Is there any way that I can change the contents of that project on server without breaking the website? I want to add some functions to it. Can I test the website after updating the code?

Comment: Depends how good you are at coding mate. I've been using Laravel for ages, but I wouldn't risk it. Spin up a local copy and make your changes there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Is it recommended? **No**

It's better to have a **staging/testing** environment setup for this. Or even better, have a **local env**.

If you have no choice but to do it on production then I suggest to do at **off hours**, when you expect no users will be online. Nonetheless, you will have to take full responsibility of your actions.